# Ext JS: add item to my existing toolbar dynamically

Tags: extjs

I've been playing with this for hours and cannot get it to work.
 I am trying to add items to a toolbar I have in my view.

I know the proxy is working from the server because I am printing results to console successfully.

please assist... I've been looking in documentation and cant see to find result

[image: view]

[image: controller]

Comment: Is it working if you skip the store load and just add one manually?

Comment: No. I beleive that is the problem that I am not adding the item in my controller correctly

Comment: Are you trying to add a whole new toolbar or a new button to an existing toolbar?

Comment: I am trying to add a button to existing toolbar

Comment: Why did you post screenshots of your code?

Comment: sorry, another site I was working on did not allow me to cut/paste

Comment: this example should be a good place start with https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ftj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method [addDocked](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.DockingContainer-method-addDocked) of panel instead method add of dockedItems. ([example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/170q))

```
function addToolbar() {
        this.up('panel').addDocked({
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            items: [{
                text: 'user 1'
            }, {
                text: 'user 2'
            }]
        });
};


var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 300,
    heigth: 300,
    title: 'Example',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'add toolbar',
        handler: addToolbar        
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'left',
        items: [{
            text: 'user 1'
        }, {
            text: 'user 2'
        }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

For adding new button to existing toolbar in your example use:

```
view.down('toolbar').add({ text: 'user X' });
```

I not sure, do you want add new toolbar with buttons, or just want to add new buttons to exist toolbar? This example add new toolbars, as you try to do in your code.

Comment: that is my problem.. I am trying to add buttons only to the existing toolbar in the view

Comment: I am trying to do this from a controller... and I cant seem to figure out how to reference the existing toolbar, and simply add a button to it

Comment: Try this: view.down('toolbar').add({ text: 'user X' });

Comment: BOOM.. that worked!  this framework is very confusing to me.  How would I ever know that view.down('kjdhfskhj') exists?  is there somewhere in the docs that examples these things?

Comment: ExtJS use few tricks everywhere. down/up - it's methods, that provide functionality from Ext.ComponentQuery methods that included in Ext.container.Container class by using mixin Ext.mixin.Queryable. Every class inherited from Ext.container.Container class provide this methods. So, panel is container, toolbar is container, your view is panel, that is container. Look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery , there many intersting things helpfull for searching components.

Comment: thanks... I'll check this out.. hopefully it makes sense to me

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
dockedItems: [
    xtype: "toolbar",
    reference: "myMenu",
    items: [...]
]
```

Then:

```
this.lookupReference("myMenu").add({text: "new button"});
```

Comment: in my controller I get the following error ... this.lookupReference is not a function

Comment: @solarissf Sorry I assumed extjs6, which version do you have?

Comment: yes I am using version 6.  I am doing this in a controller... not a view controller... does that matter.  sorry I am still trying to learn this

Comment: Try using view controller, each view is usually associated with a view controller.

Comment: okay, let me see if I can figure out how to work with a view controller

Comment: this.getView().lookupReference("myMenu").add({text: "new button"}); 

Note: I personally; avoid accessing things through "reference" instead i prefer to user "up()", "down()".